# PHP check website url using safe browsing API

Tags: php, laravel, codeigniter, safe-browsing

I am trying to check whether the url is safe or not using Google Safe browsing API

I followed following tutorial

https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/v4/get-started

I have completed following step as per above url guidence

1. Get an account
2. Create a project
3. Set up an API key

finally i end up with 
https://safebrowsing.googleapis.com/v4/...?key=API_KEY

my question is how i can pass website url to above safe browsing url

Comment: did you look at this: https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/v4/lookup-api#checking-urls? Seems like you need to make a post request.

Comment: @RaghavendraN.i read that only.my issue is how to pass parameter for that url.Thanks

Comment: Use the threatEntries array in the POST parameters: https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/v4/lookup-api#http-post-request

Comment: @scipilot.Thanks i have updated question can you check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Request body for the post request will look like this:

```
{
    "client": {
      "clientId":      "yourcompanyname",
      "clientVersion": "1.5.2"
    },
    "threatInfo": {
      "threatTypes":      ["MALWARE", "SOCIAL_ENGINEERING"],
      "platformTypes":    ["WINDOWS"],
      "threatEntryTypes": ["URL"],
      "threatEntries": [
        {"url": "http://www.urltocheck1.org/"},
        {"url": "http://www.urltocheck2.org/"},
        {"url": "http://www.urltocheck3.com/"}
      ]
    }
}
```

As you can see you need to send the url in the `threatEntries` section. But you are passing the Google url(http://www.google.com), instead add the urls you need to check.

Its self explanatory, see: url to check1.org (`"http://www.urltocheck1.org/"`)

[source](https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/v4/lookup-api#http-post-request)

Comment: @Raghavendra.Thanks for your answer.i checked with my own website url but its returning empty json .

Comment: yes it will return empty json if it doesn't find the url in their list. See **Note: If there are no matches (that is, if none of the URLs specified in the request are found on any of the lists specified in a request), the HTTP POST response simply returns an empty object in the response body**

Comment: as of now this url is marked as dangerous: `activefile.ucoz.com`. Try and see if you get any response.

Comment: @Raghavendra.now i am getting {
  "matches": [
    {
      "threatType": "MALWARE",
      "platformType": "WINDOWS",
      "threat": {
        "url": "http://activefile.ucoz.com"
      },
      "cacheDuration": "300s",
      "threatEntryType": "URL"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: Where can I find the information "clientId" and "clientVersion"? Cause when I created the project it only gave me "project name", "project id" and "project number"

Answer (score 8):

Complete the following steps to enable the API and get an API key:

1. Open the [Google Developers Console API Library.](https://console.developers.google.com/projectselector/apis/library)
2. From the project drop-down, select a project or create a new one.
3. In the **Google APIs** tab, search for and select the **Safe Browsing API**, then click **Enable API**.
4. Next, in the sidebar on the left select **Credentials**.
5. Select the **Create credentials** drop-down, then choose **API key**.
6. Depending on your application, from the Create a new key pop-up, select **Browser key** or **Server key**.
7. Enter a name for the key, set up the optional referrers or IP addresses, then click **Create**. Your key is created and displayed in a pop-up window. The key is also listed on the Credentials page.

Here is cURL code 100% working

```
curl -X POST \
  'https://safebrowsing.googleapis.com/v4/threatMatches:find?key=YOUR_KEY_HERE' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -H 'postman-token: ec7ffd77-d3fa-f017-44f9-d895efaba258' \
  -d '  {
    "client": {
      "clientId":      "yourcompanyname",
      "clientVersion": "1.5.2"
    },
    "threatInfo": {
      "threatTypes":      ["MALWARE", "SOCIAL_ENGINEERING"],
      "platformTypes":    ["WINDOWS"],
      "threatEntryTypes": ["URL"],
      "threatEntries": [
        {"url": "https://accounts-wallets.redirectme.net/webapps/57a39/websrc"},
        {"url": "http://stackoverflow.com/"}


      ]
    }
  }'
```

I got output

```
{
    "matches": [
        {
            "threatType": "SOCIAL_ENGINEERING",
            "platformType": "WINDOWS",
            "threat": {
                "url": "https://accounts-wallets.redirectme.net/webapps/57a39/websrc"
            },
            "cacheDuration": "300s",
            "threatEntryType": "URL"
        }
    ]
}
```

Python example

```
import requests

url = "https://safebrowsing.googleapis.com/v4/threatMatches:find"

querystring = {"key":"YOUR_KEY"}

payload = """

  {
    "client": {
      "clientId":      "yourcompanyname",
      "clientVersion": "1.5.2"
    },
    "threatInfo": {
      "threatTypes":      ["MALWARE", "SOCIAL_ENGINEERING"],
      "platformTypes":    ["WINDOWS"],
      "threatEntryTypes": ["URL"],
      "threatEntries": [
        {"url": "https://accounts-wallets.redirectme.net/webapps/57a39/websrc"},
        {"url": "http://stackoverflow.com/"}


      ]
    }
  }

"""
headers = {
    'content-type': "application/json",
    'cache-control': "no-cache",
    'postman-token': "460d6d44-4a55-d6ab-fb58-2ff9fb306154"
    }

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers, params=querystring)

print(response.text)
```

PHP example

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://safebrowsing.googleapis.com/v4/threatMatches:find?key=YOUR_KEY",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => '  {
"client": {
  "clientId":      "yourcompanyname",
  "clientVersion": "1.5.2"
},
"threatInfo": {
  "threatTypes":      ["MALWARE", "SOCIAL_ENGINEERING"],
  "platformTypes":    ["WINDOWS"],
  "threatEntryTypes": ["URL"],
  "threatEntries": [
    {"url": "https://accounts-wallets.redirectme.net/webapps/57a39/websrc"},
    {"url": "http://stackoverflow.com/"}


  ]
}
  }',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "content-type: application/json",
    "postman-token: b05b8d34-85f2-49cf-0f8e-03686a71e4e9"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

Comment: WOW, you need to get a novel for this kind of answer :)